# ASP Visual Basic Syntax Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to display an aggregate feed of several RSS feeds. I'm doing this with an asp page.

The problem is I'm getting the error message:
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

for the line:

```
Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = New SyndicationFeed("Feed Title", "Feed Description", New Uri("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews"), "FeedID", DateTime.Now)
```

I can't figure out where the error is. Everything I've read suggests that it's a simple syntax error, a missing comma or something.

Answer (score 0):

Is this right? It's a long time since I wrote any VB.

```
Dim feed As New SyndicationFeed("Feed Title", "Feed Description", New Uri("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews"), "FeedID", DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Because it's a different way of writing the same code.

What does the constructor for the SyndicationFeed object expect?

This error is happening at runtime, correct?

Comment: Correct, this was a runtime error. The project has been put on the back burner at this point, so I never found the solution.